# WxPython GUI library installation error

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, wxpython

After much search i choose WxPython as GUI library. I download it from [here](http://www.wxpython.org/).

When i tried to install it, it showed

[image: wxpython error]

You would note in the Folder, it has set value , which is not just one location but many locations.

On clicking next it gives error that folder path can not have `;` special characters.

When i gave it a path, it proceeds but again, it gives me an error :
[image]

And then i have to abort it.

I tried it with `unicode` wxpython only but with both release and development versions. Both failed at the same problem.

What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen that before. I would try downloading wxPython 2.9 instead. Or reinstall Python itself and then try wxPython 2.8 again. If you continue to have issues, you should ask for additional help on the wxPython users list.

Comment: I have python 2.7. I tried with wxPython 2.9 too but same error. I think the problem is with wxPython taking some environment variable. I even set PYTHONPATH to my python27 directory. No improvement.

Comment: I doubt it. I've installed wxPython dozens of times on Windows. Right now I have both 2.8 and 2.9 on my machine. I have never seen it do that. It always installs to one location. I don't know why you're seeing a different behavior.